# /usr/bin/mail equivalant for | sendmail -t

Tags: bash, shell, unix

been searching for few hours, and came to no solution.

Is there an equal expression for the bash command

```
myfile | sendmail -t
```

where my information needed for sending mails is stored in the "myfile" ?

Comment: Is `myfile` an executable, or do you mean to do `<myfile sendmail -t`?

Comment: myfile is a textfile containing information as :

'From: me@myserver.org' and 
'Subject: MySubject'

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify your OS: On my Ubuntu system, /usr/bin/mail is redirected to /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx which has a `-t` option

> ```
>   -t     The message to be sent is expected to contain a  message  header
>          with  `To:',  `Cc:',  or  `Bcc:'  fields  giving its recipients.
>          Recipients specified on the command line are ignored.
> ```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.html

Comment: i have a Debian Squeeze running the simple mailutil as far as i know.